# Spring Integration File Support

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, nio, integration-patterns

In Spring Integration how to prevent two different machines to work in the same file? I know that **nio** library(javaSE) provides a mechanism to lock File **FileLocker** but how can I implement it using Spring Integration?
A concrete example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a `org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker` implementation which can be used for the `FileReadingMessageSource` option like:

```
/**
 * Optional. Sets a {@link FileLocker} to be used to guard files against
 * duplicate processing.
 * <p>
 * <b>The supplied FileLocker must be thread safe</b>
 * @param locker a locker
 */
public void setLocker(FileLocker locker) {
```

From the XML perspective it is like this:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <file:nio-locker/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

More info is in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-namespace-support).

Another option to avoid concurrent access and duplication in differen JVMs is like using `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with the shared persistent `ConcurrentMetadataStore`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: I want to move it to another folder and I can do it. but the problem is that the FileLocker locks the file before I can do anything. I mean I want to lock the file, move it to another folder and read.  If I have 2 diff process the one who picks the file first should lock it and move to another folder. Help please